# How to propagate warnings from a "custom target" tool to Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

I'm generating a Visual Studio 2015 project using CMake. From my CMake scripts, I add a custom target (through [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html)) to generate my projects documentation (basically, it invokes doxygen tool).

When this custom target execution has warnings (notified by doxygen) (for instance the doxygen outputs `timestamp.h:15: Warning: Compound Base::Timestamp is not documented.`), is there a way to have them be listed in Visual Studio's "Error List" tab like compilation warnings? Should a specific output format be used to make Visual Studio collect the warnings and show them in its GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself....

Tool needs to prefix warning with "Warning:" and then Visual Studio catchs it and adds it as a warning in the "Error List" panel.

Just need to do some wrapping when invoking doxygen to prefix all warning by "Warning:".

Note that it also works for errors (using "Error:" prefix)